# Trying to code a counting game, this error keeps occuring and I'm not sure how to solve it (really beginner level)

Tags: python, integer, typeerror

I'm coding a counting game where the computer generates a 3-digit number, and you have to guess it. If you get a digit in the right spot, you get a strike, and if you get a digit in the wrong spot, you get a ball. I keep getting an error on line 12 of my code. Can someone help?

```
x = random.randint(1, 9) 
y = random.randint(1, 9)
z = random.randint(1, 9)
while True:
    try:
        user_guess_unlisted = int(input('What number do you want to guess?'))
    except:
        continue
    break
number_to_guess = [x, y, z] 
user_guess = list(user_guess_unlisted)
b = 0
s = 0
rloop = 1
while rloop:
    if user_guess[0] == number_to_guess[0]:
        s = s + 1
    if user_guess[0] == number_to_guess[1]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[0] == number_to_guess[2]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[1] == number_to_guess[0]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[1] == number_to_guess[1]:
        s = s + 1
    if user_guess[1] == number_to_guess[2]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[2] == number_to_guess[0]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[2] == number_to_guess[1]:
        b = b + 1
    if user_guess[2] == number_to_guess[2]:
        s = s + 1
    print(str(s) + "S " + str(b) + "B")
    if s != 3:
        b = 0
        s = 0
        userguessunlisted = input('what number do you want to guess?')
        userguess = list(userguessunlisted)
    if s == 3:
        print('you win!')
        rloop = 0
```

Comment: ty to @thisisrandy for helping me at the start! I improved a lot of this thanks to their suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an integer to a list.

You can use this:

```py
from random import randint

num = str(randint(0, 999)).zfill(3)

while True:
    while True:
        guess = input('Guess a number: ').zfill(3)
        if guess.isdigit():
            if int(guess) < 1000:
                break
    b = s = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(num):
        for j, g in enumerate(guess):
            if n == g:
                if i == j:
                    s += 1
                else:
                    b += 1
    print('Balls:', b)
    print('Strikes:', s)
    if s == 3:
        break
    print('')
```

Output:

```html
Guess a number: 123
Balls: 0
Strikes: 0

Guess a number: 456
Balls: 2
Strikes: 0

Guess a number: 654
Balls: 1
Strikes: 1

Guess a number: 647
Balls: 1
Strikes: 1

Guess a number: 657
Balls: 2
Strikes: 1

Guess a number: 675
Balls: 0
Strikes: 3
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. This really helped, I never thought of it like this, I didn't know the enumerate command existed and I'll be sure to use it in the future thank you. Just a theoretical question though, would it be possible to code this without using commands like enumerate?

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with repeated digits too?

Comment: You can convert `for i, n in enumerate(num):` to `for i in range(len(num)):` and then `n = num[i]`

Comment: I'm not sure about the repeated digits. It will probably have to be a lot more complicated.